# Youtube iframe error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, youtube

I'm using an `<iframe>` to display a YouTube video.

```html
<iframe frameborder="0" height="247" width="439"
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Llsx28sQMZQ?rel=0
               &amp;theme=dark
               &amp;modestbranding=1
               &amp;showinfo=0
               &amp;controls=0
               &amp;enablejsapi=1">
</iframe>
```

The video loads, but I'm getting errors in Chrome's console:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 410 (Gone)
>   GET http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/Llsx28sQMZQ?v=2&alt=json
>   410 (Gone)

How can I remove the errors?

Comment: i just tested your code by a small edit on the syntax.Just added < at the start. it is working . jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/azeezkallayi/de6k14zo/

Comment: try in Google Chrome...
video is loading, but i have errors in console, i don't like it
maybe trouble in my CMS plone

Comment: Working fine for me, are you sure the error isn't coming from somewhere else?

Comment: I fixed this problem...Google added some script to video and I deleted 1 function in that script

Comment: @AndrewMedvedsky can you share which script you deleted?

Comment: Check your adds in goodle analytics